# Tool for querying large numbers of csv files

Tags: c++, hive, amazon-redshift, distributed-computing, bigdata

We have large numbers of csv files, files/directories are partitioned by date and several other factors. For instance, files might be named /data/AAA/date/BBB.csv

There are thousands of files, some are in the GB range in size. Total data sizes are in the terabytes.

They are only ever appended to, and usually in bulk, so write performance is not that important. We don't want to load it into another system because there are several important processes that we run that rely on being able to stream the files quickly, which are written in c++.

I'm looking for tool/library that would allow sql like queries against the data directly off the data. I've started looking at hive, spark, and other big data tools, but its not clear if they can access partitioned data directly from a source, which in our case is via nfs.

Ideally, we would be able to define a table by giving a description of the columns, as well as partition information. Also, the files are compressed, so handling compression would be ideal.

Are their open source tools that do this? I've seen a product called Pivotal, which claims to do this, but we would rather write our own drivers for our data for an open source distributed query system.

Any leads would be appreciated.

Comment: As @isaac.hazan said, Apache Drill 1.4 gives you SQL interface to flat files. Beauty of that is, you dont have to mention the absolute file. Your folder hierarchy in partitions should do. Your example /data/AAA/date/BBB.csv - fire queries like `select count(*) from dfs.root.'/data/AAA/';`  for all files under all folders in AAA.

Comment: Does Apache Drill allow you to specify the partition function by attribute? For instance, let's say you have data in /data/TAG1_A/yyyy-mm-dd.csv, /data/TAG1_B/yyyy-mm-dd.csv, but you only want to query the data for a particular year, is there any way that Apache Drill could know only to search some of the files?
Another possible query might be across only some of the values for TAG1, that it wouldn't have to go through all of the TAG1_XXX files. I was hoping it would work more like partitioned tables in a database.

Answer (score 0):

Spark can be a solution. It is in memory distributed processing engine. Data can be loaded into memory on multiple nodes in the cluster and can be processed in memory. You do not need to copy data to another system.

Here are the steps for your case:

1. Build multiple node spark cluster
2. Mount NFS on to one of the nodes
3. Then you have to load data temporarily into memory in the form of RDD and start processing it

It provides

1. Support for programming languages like scala, python, java etc
2. Supports SQL Context and data frames. You can define structure to the data and start accessing using SQL Queries
3. Support for several compression algorithms

Limitations

1. Data has to be fit into memory to be processed by Spark
2. You need to use data frames to define structure on data after which you can query the data using sql embedded in programming languages like scala, python, java etc
3. There are subtle differences between traditional SQL in RDBMS and SQL in distributed systems like spark. You need to aware of those.

With hive, you need to have data copied to HDFS. As you do not want to copy the data to another system, hive might not be solution.

Comment: For Spark, it sounds like you have to manually load the data into memory. I was hoping for something where you could map your partitions so when you query across files you don't have to explicitly load each file.